# command not found and not a valid identifier

Tags: linux, bash

EDIT: After posting it looks like example input I included didn't get formatted properly in the post. I added extra new lines in the block quotes to make it easier to read.

So this is a two part, and I'm sorry if I'm duplicating anywhere. I read what looked like the relevant topics to the two errors I got.

I wrote a script that interfaces with the API of a wireless controller, and I handed that off to a customer. I tested the script on two different flavors of Linux (albeit both Debian), both of which worked. Here's the script in it's entirety.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=~/mac_add.log
cOpt="-i -H Accept:application/xml -H Content-Type:application/xml -X POST -k -u"

read -p "Enter IP: " ipAddr
if [[ $ipAddr =~ ^([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then {
  echo "IP address $ipAddr... OKAY"
} else {
  echo "Invalid IP address"
  exit
} fi

read -p "Enter username: " user
if [[ $user =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$ ]]; then {
  echo "User $user... OKAY"
} else {
  echo "Invalid email address"
  exit
} fi

read -sp "Enter password: " passwd
echo ""
read -p "Enter name of domain: " domain
domain="${domain// /%20}"
read -p "Role ID: " role
read -p "Enter file with MAC addresses: " inFile

if [ ! -f $inFile ]; then {
  echo "$inFile not found"
  exit
} fi

cat $inFile | while read line; do {
  name="$(echo $line|sed 's/\(.*\),.*/\1/')"
  mac="$(echo $line|sed 's/.*,//')"
  if [[ $name =~ ^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\ ]+$ ]]; then {
    if [[ $mac =~ ^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}$ ]]; then {
      curl $cOpt $user:$passwd https://$ipAddr:3000/macdevices?active_domain_name=office -d "<macdevice><name>$name</name><role_id>$role</role_id><address>$mac</address></macdevice>"
    } else {
      echo "The MAC address $mac is invalid" >> $LOG
    } fi
  } else {
    echo "The name $name is invalid" >> $LOG
  } fi
} done
```

The input file is a CSV file. Each line is should be of the format "name,MAC". Below are the contents of the file I used for testing.

> name4,00:19:92:ab:cd:3f
>
> name3,ag:10:12:31:32:32
>
> name2,3214:1f:ed:ab:22
>
> name1,AB:CD:EF:12:33:44
>
> 5name,AB:CD:EF:12:33:44
>
> paul smith,AB:CD:EF:12:33:44

I handed this to the customer, and this is what they got.

> $ bash mac-add.bsh
>
> : command not found:
>
> : command not found:
>
> Enter IP: redacted
>
> ': not a valid identifier: `ipAddr
>
> mac-add.bsh: line 7: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
>
> mac-add.bsh: line 7: syntax error near `^(['
>
> 'ac-add.bsh: line 7: `if [[ $ipAddr =~ ^([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then {
>
> Last return status: 2

So I thought maybe they don't have the version of bash that supports regex. They say they're running 4.1.3 which I believe should. I'm not entirely sure what flavor Linux, but really I just want to know what's wrong with this so I can work on portability. I'm also open to using a different language if needed.

My initial thoughts are to simplify the script by removing LOG and cOpt, the latter because I just used it to make the cURL call one line. I would also remove the regex checks.

Comment: Your use of `{` and `}` is a bit odd. I think you can omit all of them; your script should still work (as well as it does now) and be more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the braces simply for formatting in the text editor. It allows me to collapse functions and large conditionals/loops. It just became habit, but you're right, they can be removed. I think you may be on to something in your answer too. I've noticed this when pasting from this same editor that sometimes I have to do a little extra effort with newline characters. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your line endings.

If a shell script has Windows-style line endings, a line like `foo` will look like `foo^M`; when it prints the error message `foo^M: Command not found`, the `^M` will move the cursor to the beginning of the line, and the rest of the message will overwrite the command name. (Here I use `^M` to represent the carriage return character).

You can run

```
bash mac-add.bsh 2>&1 | cat -A
```

to see the error message including the return characters (or `cat -v` if your `cat` doesn't have the `-A` option).

From your description, the Windows-style line endings may have been added somewhere between you and the customer.